Running java selenium testcases inside docker container via azure pipleine getting error unable to load element
This is my docker file 
# Base image with Maven and JDK
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-11

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install necessary dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    xvfb \
    curl \
    unzip \
    jq \
    libxss1 \
    libappindicator1 \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    fonts-liberation \
    libasound2 \
    libnspr4 \
    libnss3 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxtst6 \
    lsb-release \
    xdg-utils \
    libgbm1 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libxcb-dri3-0 \
    libgl1-mesa-glx \
    libxrender1 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxi6 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libxcursor1 \
    libxinerama1

# Download versions JSON and install Google Chrome
RUN curl -s https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/last-known-good-versions-with-downloads.json > /tmp/versions.json && \
    CHROME_URL=$(jq -r '.channels.Stable.downloads.chrome[] | select(.platform=="linux64") | .url' /tmp/versions.json) && \
    wget -q --continue -O /tmp/chrome-linux64.zip $CHROME_URL && \
    unzip /tmp/chrome-linux64.zip -d /opt/chrome && \
    chmod +x /opt/chrome/chrome-linux64/chrome

# Install ChromeDriver
RUN CHROMEDRIVER_URL=$(jq -r '.channels.Stable.downloads.chromedriver[] | select(.platform=="linux64") | .url' /tmp/versions.json) && \
    wget -q --continue -O /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip $CHROMEDRIVER_URL && \
    unzip /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip -d /opt/chromedriver && \
    chmod +x /opt/chromedriver/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver

# Set environment variables
ENV CHROME_BIN /opt/chrome/chrome-linux64/chrome
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_DIR /opt/chromedriver
ENV PATH $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR:$PATH
ENV DISPLAY=:99

# Clean up
RUN rm /tmp/chrome-linux64.zip /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip /tmp/versions.json


# Default command to run tests
CMD ["sh", "-c", "Xvfb :99 -ac & mvn clean test -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/opt/chromedriver/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver -Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps='' -Dchrome.options.args='--headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage --remote-allow-origins=* --disable-software-rasterizer --disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor'"]

Context:
I am using the above docker image inside my azure pipleine as container to run java selenium test cases.
Error:
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href='ExcelDataListOverall.asp']"}
  (Session info: chrome=129.0.6668.70)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1160.119.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.14.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [62eccac0565dae1b9e5321e8200627f3, findElement {using=xpath, value=//a[@href='ExcelDataListOverall.asp']}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 129.0.6668.70, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 129.0.6668.70 (df87d5cf12b1..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:41060}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:41060/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 129.0.6668.70, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 62eccac0565dae1b9e5321e8200627f3

Issue faced:
But that href element is getting launched when i run from my machine or from other windows server. I have increased timeout as well it is not working. And when i took snapshots of that i could that specific element is not loaded at all.**
Tested multiple way but failing. Any idea upon this**


I think here the problem is not in the docker because if it runs without error it does mean it runs all the commands and installs everything correctly
here you need to add more wait for this element try to use Explicate wait for this particular element for 60 SC, in case the element exists and you can run the same test in your local.. try to use this xpath //a[contains(text(),'ExcelDataListOverall')]", also try to add another timeout wait driver. manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.of seconds(60));
also, ensure that the browser is hedless>true

Nope i have increased the time out in chromesetting.java
public WebDriver getDriver() {
  
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(addAll());

    
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));  // 60 seconds for page load
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));   // 10 seconds implicit wait

    return driver;
}

But still getting the error no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(),'ExcelDataListOverall')]"}

but try to run the same scenario in your local and check the result because the error does mean the element is not correct or not found so try to run the same in your local
another way to ensure, try to get chropath extension if you are using Chrome and in the same page that includes this element  and use //a[contains(text(),'ExcelDataListOverall')] and check how many elements there it should show 1 element found if the result is zero try to get the path of this element, may be the element into a frame so this way will help you to know if the element is existing or no

I was able to fix this issue when running as windows container. Linux container due to Linux OS at the backend doesn't support few frames.
